# Obtaining Wordpress custom widget options using AJAX

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I am writing a custom widget on WordPress. This custom widget will be used to display a specific item belonging to a Custom Field that I have also set up.

With the code blow, I'm having some troubles:

```
public function form( $instance ) {?>
        <?php
        $args = array(
            'hide_empty' => true,
            'exclude' => 2,
        );
        
        $categories = get_categories($args); ?>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'team' ) ); ?>">Team:</label>
            <select id="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'team' ) ); ?>" name="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_name( 'team' ) ); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['team']; ?>" style="width:100%;" >
                <?php
                    foreach($categories as $team) {
                        echo '<option value="'.$team->term_id.'">'.$team->name.'</option>';
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
        </p>
        
        <?php
        $args_players = array(
            'post_type' => 'player'
        );
        
        $players = get_posts($args_players);
        ?>
        
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'player' ) ); ?>">Player:</label>
            <select id="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'player' ) ); ?>" name="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_name( 'player' ) ); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['player']; ?>" style="width:100%;" >
                <?php
                    foreach($players as $player) {
                        echo '<option value="'.$player->ID.'">'.$player->post_title.'</option>';
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
        </p>
        
    <?php
    }
```

The Custom Post Field is called "Player" and the idea is to display a "Featured Player" on the sidebar. Each "Player" belongs to a "Team", that is selected in this specific fragment of the previous code:

```
$args = array(
                'hide_empty' => true,
                'exclude' => 2,
            );
            
            $categories = get_categories($args); ?>
            <p>
                <label for="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'team' ) ); ?>">Team:</label>
                <select id="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'team' ) ); ?>" name="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_name( 'team' ) ); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['team']; ?>" style="width:100%;" >
                    <?php
                        foreach($categories as $team) {
                            echo '<option value="'.$team->term_id.'">'.$team->name.'</option>';
                        }
                    ?>
                </select>
            </p>
```

This works as expected, but the other fragment of the code should gather "Players" from the selected "Team".

I have tried several options but I can't seem to find something that actually works, and I was wondering if I could use AJAX to achieve this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you can access the widget's options like this:

```
public function ajax_call(){
    $instance = $this->get_settings();
    wp_send_json(array(
        'instance' => $instance
    ));
}
```